# Invoke a API call directing to success or failure with anchor tag created using java script

Tags: javascript, angular, anchor, createelement

I have a button to behave it to be an anchor tag or link.Added below code when clicked on button.

```
download() {
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        //link.href = this.downloadFile; // can i call a function here which has API invoking?
        link.onclick = this.downloadFile;
        link.click();
}
downloadFile() { 
        this.Service.download(
            id
        ).subscribe((data: any) => {
        },
        (error: any) => {

        });
    }
```

How can i call this function with anchor tag created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using link.onclick, use the addEventListener method on your link to register your download method :

```
    function download() {

      var link = document.createElement('a'); 
      document.body.appendChild(link);

      link.addEventListener('click', this.downloadFile);
      link.click();
    }

    function downloadFile() { 
        console.log("Here we go");
    }
```

BUT be carreful because if your method downloadFile is a class method, the "this" in the downloadFile function will be undefined or equal to window global object, and you will have to hard bind the this context using link.addEventListener('click', this.downloadFile.bind(this));